# How to make part of the model not be subdivided？

Tags: subdivision-surface

I would like to create a standard square groove in the plane, just like this.[image]

But when i switch to object mode, it just almost disappear because I used subdivision.
[image]

Comment: @Tak You haven't even given him 1 minute to accept your answer before you ask for it? Give him a chance to learn how to use the site on his own and don't explicitly ask for acceptance until *he* says it solved his problem.

Comment: @pycoder the reason I do this is that I can see on the newsfeed of the questions, some new users never mark the question they asked as solved  and never come back to the site, which sometimes makes it harder for people facing the same problem. I asked him to accept only if it solved his problem to encourage/remind him do this incase it was helpful for him.

Comment: @Tak I understand your motivation for doing this, but it comes across as begging for reputation. Users should be advised to wait until accepting in case other users can provide better answers. Asking people to accept (when they have not indicated that the answer has helped them) encourages people to accept the *first* answer, not the *best* one. If they comment or indicate the answer has helped, *then* teach them about how accepting works.

Answer (score 7):

Same example:
[image: Edit Mode]

Becomes:
[image: Object Mode]

The solution is:
1. Select the edges you don't want to be subdivided
[image: Select edges]

2. In the right bar (Press N to show it) set the "Mean Crease" value to 1 (it sets how much the selected edges don't react to subdivision smoothness Edit: note that the face is still subdivided but the subfaces created by subdivision mantain the original position. No smoothness.). They'll become violet.
   [image: Edge crease]
3. Turn back to Edit Mode and enjoy
   [image: Works!]

Comment: Edge crease, awesome! Didn't know this was a feature, but it's very useful to know, thanks.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the topology still gets subdivided, it just uses simple subdivision instead of smooth subdivision. ;-)

Comment: Yes! Right! I just edited the post adding that information. Thank for the advise. :-)

Comment: Another solution would be to use supporting loopcuts in that area (i.e. to run a loopcut along selected faces on screenshot). This will create smooth transition (and add more geometry which is always a choice)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this:

- I had a cube with subdivision done to it as shown below:

[image]

- Let's say I don't want the upper face to be subdivided. First switch into edit mode and choose face selection as shown below:

[image]

- Select the upper four faces which you want to be one face as shown below:

[image]

- Go to the mesh menu, then Faces, then `Make Edge/Face` as shown below:

[image]

- Then they will be back into one face again as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This cannot be used if one doesn't want to apply the Subdivision Surface modifier, leaving it unapplied in the modifier stack.